# iOS publish private code framework on cocoapods

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, frameworks, cocoapods

I need to publish a MySDK.framework (mixed obj-c + Swift) on cocoapods. I followed steps in [Publish a Universal Binary iOS Framework in Swift using CocoaPods](https://eladnava.com/publish-a-universal-binary-ios-framework-in-swift-using-cocoapods/)

When I run `pod install`, it says:

```
Analyzing dependencies
Fetching podspec for `MySDK` from `..`
Downloading dependencies
Using AFNetworking (3.1.0)
Using Crashlytics (3.9.3)
Using FXBlurView (1.6.4)
Using Fabric (1.7.2)
Using HexColors (2.3.0)
Using JSONModel (1.7.0)
Using KVOController (1.2.0)
Using Masonry (1.0.2)
Using SAMKeychain (1.5.3)
Using SDWebImage (3.8.2)
Using SnapKit (3.0.2)
Using SwiftyBeaver (1.2.2)
Using Toast (3.1.0)
Using YYImage (1.0.4)
Using MySDK (0.0.1)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
Sending stats
Pod installation complete! There is 1 dependency from the Podfile and 15 total pods installed.
```

But **MySDK.zip** is not downloaded nor installed in Pods project, so Xcode complains about missing module MySDK (at import MySDK).

**MySDK.podspec**

```
#
# Be sure to run `pod lib lint MySDK.podspec' to ensure this is a
# valid spec before submitting.
#
# Any lines starting with a # are optional, but their use is encouraged
# To learn more about a Podspec see http://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html
#

Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name             = 'MySDK'
  s.version          = '0.0.1'
  s.summary          = 'A short description of MySDK.'

# This description is used to generate tags and improve search results.
#   * Think: What does it do? Why did you write it? What is the focus?
#   * Try to keep it short, snappy and to the point.
#   * Write the description between the DESC delimiters below.
#   * Finally, don't worry about the indent, CocoaPods strips it!

  s.description      = <<-DESC
                   MySDK framework for iOS.

                   * TODO: where docs are?
                   DESC

  s.homepage         = 'http://www.MySDK.com'
  # s.screenshots     = 'www.example.com/screenshots_1', 'www.example.com/screenshots_2'
  s.license          = { :type => 'Apache 2', :file => 'LICENSE' }
  s.author           = { 'me' => 'my-email@email.com' }

  s.ios.deployment_target = '8.0'
  s.source            = { :http => 'http://working-link.to/MySDK.framework.zip' }
  s.ios.vendored_frameworks = 'MySDK.framework'

  s.frameworks = 'UIKit'

  s.dependency 'AFNetworking', '~> 3.1.0'
  s.dependency 'Crashlytics', '~> 3.9.3'
  s.dependency 'Fabric', '~> 1.7.2'
  s.dependency 'JSONModel', '~> 1.7.0'
  s.dependency 'KVOController', '~> 1.2.0'
  s.dependency 'Masonry', '~> 1.0.2'
  s.dependency 'SAMKeychain', '~> 1.5.3'
  s.dependency 'SDWebImage', '~> 3.8.2'
  s.dependency 'SnapKit', '~> 3.0.0'
  s.dependency 'SwiftyBeaver', '~> 1.2.2'
  s.dependency 'Toast', '~> 3.1.0'
  s.dependency 'YYImage', '~> 1.0.4'

end
```

- If I add the framework to embed frameworks, everything is working as expected.
- Tried clean Pods cache, no luck

Please help!

Comment: Any progress? I'm having the same problem! Did you post the question to cocoapods directly?

Comment: @AaronBratcher, yes posting the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `:podspec` instead of `:path` inside Podfile made it work (because in the tutorial provided `:path` is used):

```
target 'MySDK-example' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for MySDK-example
  pod 'MySDK', :podspec => '..'
end
```