# How to publish a prebuilt iOS fat framework as CocoaPod pacakge

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I have never made a pod package nor I actually use them, I'm trying to create a pod package and deploy it.

So I have created a fully working SDK.framework which is fat iOS library for amd64 and x86_64 - I have created podspec in very similar way to this post

[iOS publish private code framework on cocoapods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47704497/ios-publish-private-code-framework-on-cocoapods)

Now the command "pod trunk push sdk.podspec" output:

- ERROR | [iOS] xcodebuild: Returned an unsuccessful exit code. You can use `--verbose` for more information.

Which is very odd because the framework is prebuilt and I only need to deploy... what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

this problem is that the spec file failed to pass when verifying the correctness of the spec file,you can use `pod trunk push sdk.podspec --verbose`  to track the line where the error is. Generally, there will be suggestions for modification,i look forward to seeing your error message

Comment: Thanks, the output is xcodebuild trying to build the package and failing, as the framework is already build and I need only to deploy

Comment: you mean to skip the build of SDK.framework during deployment, right?

Comment: Correct, the SDK is already built and in binary form.

Comment: Before you deploy, verify that the .podspec file is legal, use  ```pod spec lint sdk.podspec --verbose``` to view the error inside